how can i increment cell value by 1 (number format and date)




A
B




1
No
Date


2
1
01/01/2024


3




4




5
2
01/02/2024


6




7




8
3
01/03/2024



When I tried auto fill, obviously failed. It doesn't seem to skip blank cell and I dont want to do it manually by putting =A2+1 on cell A5 and so on.
All i have going now is for the date im using on Cell B5 =IF(ISBLANK(A5),"", B2+1)

Starting from the second line,  does the number increases by 1 every 2 lines, and the date increases by 1 day?

Hi Emily, Yes the date increases by 1 every 2 lines. im having trouble with the number. when using autofill.  im manually using =cell num+1

Hello, what is the question here ?

@xhamsterIT, according to your sample,  the number column could try fomula =IF(MOD(ROW(A2)+1,3)=0,(ROW(A2)+1)/3,""), [image]: https://i.sstatic.net/MBwsHKUp.png

AutoFill will work if you start from selecting three rows: one with your data and two blank rows, then fill down.

=IF(MOD(ROW(A2)+1,3)=0,(ROW(A2)+1)/3,"") this actually solved the problem. now im having conflict with the Cell B5 =IF(ISBLANK(A5),"", B2+1) it does display date when blank 01/01/1900. is there any way to remove it? @Emily

Use condition IF(A5="","",B2+1) instead of ISBLANK.

Yes, @xhamsterIT MGonet's suggestion works perfectly.

Thanks i will try this. Thanks guys!! got it working. i will now try to do a macro to get the same output. Cheers!! have a wonderful day everyone! @MGonet and Emily
